# DropDownItemClick Event not firing

Tags: c#, event-handling

I have this DropDownButton that is programatically added to a ToolStripMenuItem. When I click on it, I want it to fire an event, but it doesn't do anything inside the Event block. Please review this code and comment on what I've done wrong.

Thanks

```
private void privateChatToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Icon icon1 = new Icon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("Chat_NET_Client.pm.ico"));
    Bitmap bmp = icon1.ToBitmap();
    ToolStripMenuItem item = new ToolStripMenuItem(listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text, bmp);
    item.DropDownItemClicked += item_Click;
    chatsToolStripMenuItem.DropDownItems.Add(item);
}

void onClick(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
    inPM = true;
    txtLog.Visible = false;
    pmBox.Visible = true;
    mainToolStripMenuItem1.Enabled = true;
    pmBox.Clear();
    curPM = e.ClickedItem.Text;

    Invoke(new _appendLog(appendLog), "STARTING PM :D");
    using (StreamReader r = new StreamReader(appData + "\\" + e.ClickedItem.Text + ".dat"))
    {
        string line;

        while (r.ReadLine() != null)
        {
            line = r.ReadLine();
            pmBox.AppendText(line + Environment.NewLine);
            pmBox.ScrollToCaret();
        }
    }
}
```

Final Notes:
The DropDown item DOES get created and added, the problem is that it doesn't fire the event when it is clicked!

Answer (score 1):

You are calling wrong event i think.  do as below

```
item.DropDownItemClicked += item_Click;
```

change to

```
item.DropDownItemClicked += onClick;
```

Answer (score 1):

Well over here on this line:

```
item.DropDownItemClicked += item_Click;
```

You're binding the `DropDownItem` to a different event `item_Click`:
Either rename your event or just bind it to the correct one:

```
void item_Click(object sender, ToolStripItemClickedEventArgs e)
{
   // do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Did you rename the event handler ?

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem. You need to pass handler through constructor of ToolStripMenuItem.